# Passing Data between view Controller and a Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to pass a string value namely,`'_passedDataDate'` from a `viewController` to a `TableView Controller`. And there in the `TableViewController`,I am trying to keep it in a array namely,`'_dateArray'`. while trying to do so, at first a `nil` object gets inserted and then the real object. how to avoid this nil value getting added?

Here is the code bellow,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _dateString = _passedDataDate;
    if(_dateString){
        [_dateArray addObject:_passedDataDate];
        NSLog(@"Added Passed Data");
        NSLog(@"%ld",[_dateArray count]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"No object Added");
        NSLog(@"%ld",[_dateArray count]);
    }



}
```

Output is as follow:

No object Added
0
Added Passed Data
1

Why No object Added is getting printed? I do not want it what shall Ido about it?

Also,I get the below warning,

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: show the part of code where you are passing `_passedDataDate`

Comment: ''-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    TableViewController *tableView = [segue destinationViewController];
    tableView.passedDataDate = _dateData;
    tableView.passedDataDestination = _destinationData;
    
}

- (IBAction)viewMyList:(id)sender {
    _dateData = _dateString;
    _destinationData = _descriptionString;
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pass" sender:nil];
    
    }''

Comment: I suggest you look up a tutorial and follow the procedure. Its really messed up code. And please follow correct naming conventions too.

Comment: post the part of code where your _dateString is initialized and changed

Comment: @J.Hunter it is in the initial code. Also, the value in 'passedDataDate' is assigned to _dateString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Segue inside the button action.

Hide the segue

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pass" sender:nil];
```

And try this :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"pass"]) 
    {
        TableViewController *tableView = [segue destinationViewController];
        tableView.passedDataDate = @"HAI";tableView.passedDataDestination = @"Hellio";
     }
 }
```